# How can I use my model for a single picture?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I trained a machine and I got the model now.
This is my code:( It works fine but i wanna use it for a single picture.)

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import shuffle
from keras.utils  import to_categorical
import pickle
def load_rand():
    X=[]
    dir_path='D:/dataset/train'
    for sub_dir in tqdm(os.listdir(dir_path)):
        print(sub_dir)
        path_main=os.path.join(dir_path,sub_dir)
        i=0
        for img_name in os.listdir(path_main):
            if i>=6:
                break
            img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_main,img_name))
            img=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            X.append(img)
            i+=1
    return X
X=load_rand()
X=np.array(X)
X.shape
def show_subpot(X,title=False,Y=None):
    if X.shape[0]==36:
        f, ax= plt.subplots(6,6, figsize=(40,60))
        list_fruits=['rottenoranges', 'rottenapples', 'freshbanana', 'freshoranges', 'rottenbanana', 'freshapples']
        for i,img in enumerate(X):
            ax[i//6][i%6].imshow(img, aspect='auto')
            if title==False:
                ax[i//6][i%6].set_title(list_fruits[i//6])
            elif title and Y is not None:
                ax[i//6][i%6].set_title(Y[i])
        plt.show()
    else:
        print('Cannot plot')
show_subpot(X)
del X
def load_rottenvsfresh():
    quality=['fresh', 'rotten']
    X,Y=[],[]
    z=[]
    for cata in tqdm(os.listdir('D:/dataset/train')):
        if quality[0] in cata:
            path_main=os.path.join('D:/dataset/train',cata)
            for img_name in os.listdir(path_main):
                img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_main,img_name))
                img=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
                img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                z.append([img,0])
        else:
            path_main=os.path.join('D:/dataset/train',cata)
            for img_name in os.listdir(path_main):
                img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_main,img_name))
                img=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
                img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                z.append([img,1])
    print('Shuffling your data.....')
    shuffle(z)
    for images, labels in tqdm(z):
        X.append(images);Y.append(labels)
    return X,Y
X,Y=load_rottenvsfresh()
Y=np.array(Y)
X=np.array(X)
y_ser=pd.Series(Y)
y_ser.value_counts()
def load_rottenvsfresh_valset():
    quality=['fresh', 'rotten']
    X,Y=[],[]
    z=[]
    for cata in tqdm(os.listdir('D:/dataset/test')):
        if quality[0] in cata:
            path_main=os.path.join('D:/dataset/test',cata)
            for img_name in os.listdir(path_main):
                img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_main,img_name))
                img=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
                img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                z.append([img,0])
        else:
            path_main=os.path.join('D:/dataset/test',cata)
            for img_name in os.listdir(path_main):
                img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_main,img_name))
                img=cv2.resize(img,(100,100))
                img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                z.append([img,1])
    print('Shuffling your data.....')
    shuffle(z)
    for images, labels in tqdm(z):
        X.append(images);Y.append(labels)
    return X,Y
X_val,Y_val=load_rottenvsfresh_valset()
Y_val=np.array(Y_val)
X_val=np.array(X_val)
y_ser=pd.Series(Y_val)
y_ser.value_counts()
import keras 
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout, Conv2D,MaxPooling2D , Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization, SeparableConv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
X=X/255.0
X_val=X_val/255.0
model.evaluate(X_val,Y_val)
model=load_model('D:/dataset/rottenvsfresh.h5')
from keras.models import Model, load_model
new_model=load_model('D:/dataset/rotten.h5')
new_model.evaluate(X_val,Y_val)
plt.imshow(X_val[0])
model.predict(X_val[0].reshape(1,100,100,3))
show_subpot(X_val[-36*11:-36*10])
#model.predict(X_val[-36*11:-36*10])
y_pred =model.predict(X_val[-36*11:-36*10]) 
np.round(y_pred).astype(int)
```

I trained the model to classify rotten fruit from the fresh one. I do not have enough experince in machine learning and this is my first project. I could do this in general but now I wanna try the model for single pictures as input. ( I copy pasted the codes from jupiter cells.)
I tried a lot to use the model for a single picture as input but it dosen't work.

This is how I tried: (But it gives wrong output.)

```
# Load the image you want to classify
img_path = "C:/Users/d/Desktop/hjbjkh/lo.jpg"
img = load_image(img_path)

# Preprocess the image and prepare it for classification
img = np.array([img])  # Add a batch dimension

# Print a summary of the model's architecture
model.summary()

# Use the classification model to predict the class of the image
predictions = model.predict(img)

# Get the predicted class
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions)

# If desired, display the image and the predicted class
print("Predicted class:", predicted_class)
plt.imshow(img[0])
```

Edited part from what i get from comments:

```
# Import PyTorch
import torch

# Load the image you want to classify
img_path = "C:/Users/d/Desktop/hjbjkh/ad.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

# Resize the image to the desired dimensions
img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))

# Convert the image from BGR color space to RGB color space
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Convert the image from a NumPy array to a PyTorch tensor
img = torch.from_numpy(img)

# Add a batch dimension to the image
img = img.unsqueeze(0)

# Convert the image from a PyTorch tensor to a NumPy array
img = img.numpy()

# Use the classification model to predict the class of the image
predictions = model.predict(img)

# Get the predicted class
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions)


# If desired, display the image and the predicted class
print("Predicted class:", predicted_class)
plt.imshow(img[0])
```

Comment: If the output is wrong maybe the model has trouble with that example. You could use `.unsqueeze(0)` to make the image look like a batch and make it accetaptable to the model

Comment: @Caridorc I used what you said in the edited part of my question. you can check it. but my problem is that I only get one answer which is 0. In the test file we get true answers but here we got only 0.